# GroupedDragging in Qt4

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt4

In Qt5 I can set the GroupedDragging dock option to my QMainWindow to allow dragging a tabbed dock widget into a new docking area. Is there a way to achieve this same functionality in Qt4. Additionally, when dragging a tab to a new docking area can I keep it in the form of a single tab instead of the tab bar disappearing.

Comment: No, you can't. At least, not without countless hours of headaches and possibly unreliable implementation attempts. QMainWindow has its own private and quite delicate layout, which is still somehow limited no matter the improvements that newer Qt5 versions brought. The only acceptable way to achieve this would be to completely manage the QMainWindow layout on your own, and it would still **not** be fully reliable, unless you're ready (and have enough experience) to manage things like internal layout mechanisms, outside client area events, cross-platform issues, QStyle possibilities, etc...